# Hadoop 2.7.5 - AM Container launch error

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I've seen multiple questions related to AM Container launch error but none of them resolved it for me.

I've setup Hadoop 2.7.5 on my Mac OSX High Sierra laptop and was trying the example mapreduce job for Pi:

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.5.jar pi 2 4
```

I have all the services running:

```
$ jps
69555 NameNode
69954 NodeManager
69750 SecondaryNameNode
70806 JobHistoryServer
69643 DataNode
71194 Jps
69866 ResourceManager
```

This is what I get as output:

```
$ hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.5.jar pi  2 4
Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 4
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/tez/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/03/25 13:30:42 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Starting Job
18/03/25 13:30:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
18/03/25 13:30:43 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
18/03/25 13:30:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
18/03/25 13:30:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1521963635636_0004
18/03/25 13:30:44 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1521963635636_0004
18/03/25 13:30:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://AbdealiJK-Mac.local:8088/proxy/application_1521963635636_0004/
18/03/25 13:30:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1521963635636_0004
18/03/25 13:30:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1521963635636_0004 running in uber mode : false
18/03/25 13:30:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/03/25 13:30:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1521963635636_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1521963635636_0004 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1521963635636_0004_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://AbdealiJK-Mac.local:8088/cluster/app/application_1521963635636_0004Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: File /Users/abdealijk/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk/appcache/application_1521963635636_0004/container_1521963635636_0004_02_000001 does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
18/03/25 13:30:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
Job Finished in 7.986 seconds
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost/user/abdealijk/QuasiMonteCarlo_1521964841970_1162968685/out/reduce-out
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1820)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.estimatePi(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.run(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.QuasiMonteCarlo.main(QuasiMonteCarlo.java:363)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

The error seems to say:

```
File /Users/abdealijk/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk/appcache/application_1521963635636_0004/container_1521963635636_0004_02_000001 does not exist
```

But when I check it:

```
$ ls -lh ~/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk/appcache/application_1521963635636_0004
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 abdealijk  staff   192B Mar 25 13:30 filecache
```

I have permissions to write, I own that folder and so on. But the container folder is still not being created there.

**Edit 1**: Logs with YARN-RM / yarn command

I've tried checking the logs in YARN-RM webUI and also with `yarn logs -applicationId` but both of them say that as the AM-container was not launched, no logs are found.

**Edit 2**: This is what I get in that folder

```
$ tree ~/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk/appcache/application_1522077498598_0003
~/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk/appcache/application_1522077498598_0003
└── filecache
    ├── 10
    │   └── job.splitmetainfo
    ├── 11
    │   └── job.jar
    │       └── job.jar
    ├── 12
    │   └── job.split
    └── 13
        └── job.xml

6 directories, 4 files
```

No folders for container :(

**Edit 3**: My core-site.xml has:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <!-- <value>hdfs://localhost/</value> -->
        <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I have tried both with `hdfs://localhost/` and `hdfs://localhost:8020/`.

I think this may be an issue with the URI

Comment: It actually says `File does not exist: hdfs://localhost... ` Use hdfs commands to check that path

Comment: The path with the hdfs is the second error (which I believe is being caused because the mappers failed in the first task)

Comment: Did you `check application tracking page:`, as the error says?

Comment: Yes, The app tracking page says there are no logs found ... It says no containers were created.

Comment: Try `chmod -R 777  ~/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk`, and do it again

Comment: @cricket_007 Tried that. still the same issue. Note that for every app a new folder would be created at the `~/hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/abdealijk/appcache/<appID>`. The new folder will be rwxr-wr-w with me (abdealijk) as owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what fixed it:

**hdfs-site.xml:**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>${user.home}/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>${user.home}/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hadoop-tmpdir</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Execute:

```
$ rm -rf ~/hadoop  # To delete my previous folders
$ mkdir -p ~/hadoop/hdfs/namenode
$ mkdir -p ~/hadoop/hdfs/datanode
$ hdfs namenode -format
```

And now executing the command allowed the containers to launch successfully.